# Using environment variables in React application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Our JavaScript resource just quit, so I, knowing nothing about front-end development, need to get my UI stood up. I'm trying to use an environment variable in the javascript, and it seems like there are 100 different ways to do it.

All I know is this is a react/node app. I start it with `npm run start`. It needs an endpoint I've defined in my .bash_profile, `XREFS_BACK_URL`. I thought I could just use `process.env.XREFS_BACK_URL`, but apparently that has to be defined in some file? I don't know what file or where it should be located.

Sorry to be so clueless - this just landed in my lap and I have to get it up quickly!

Update:

I created a `.env` file in the root directory. It's one line:

```
REACT_APP_XREFS_BACK_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

In my code, I try to use it like so:

```
var endpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_XREFS_BACK_URL;
console.log("endpoint is " + endpoint);
```

But the console shows that `endpoint` is `UNDEFINED`.

My package.json is here:

```
{
  "name": "bulletin-board",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "match-sorter": "^2.2.1",
    "namor": "^1.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-draggable": "^2.2.0",
    "react-table": "^6.8.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.*[.](jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|less|LESS|css|CSS)$": "EmptyModule"
    },
    "preprocessorIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
      "<rootDir>/EmptyModule.js"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using webpack? if so theres things that take them and burn them in.

Comment: I don't believe I am...

Comment: does the package.json `start` script call `react-scripts` ?

Comment: Yes, it calls react-scripts.

Comment: ah bingo... you have a really old version of react-scripts. try updating your react-scripts and restarting. `npm install --save-dev react-scripts@1.1.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app was made with `create-react-app`. Here are the docs for adding / referencing environment variables: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables

Create a file in the root folder called `.env` with the contents:

`REACT_APP_XREFS_BACK_URL=put_whatever_here`

Then access this variable in your JavaScript via:

`process.env.REACT_APP_XREFS_BACK_URL`

Comment: I put the .env file in the root of the app, but `REACT_APP_XREFS_BACK_URL` is still `UNDEFINED`.

Comment: did you restart the application

Comment: I promise I did!

Comment: can you update your question with your `.env` file, the code where you are console logging it and the version of `react-scripts` in your package.json

Comment: it's `process.env.REACT_APP_XREFS_BACK_URL;`  not `process.env.XREFS_BACK_URL;`

Comment: Sorry, I thought `REACT_APP_` was automatically prepended. But it's still undefined, even with that change.

Comment: post your entire package.json. also what file is your console log in? is it within the `src` folder?

Comment: I'm viewing the console.log in the browser window. Will post package.json.

Comment: i know that's where you're looking for the log.. I mean what file is that log written in? you can't access `process.env` from the browser console

Comment: I'm not aware of any file being written to... I don'r see any.

Comment: also to clarify... is your package.json also at the root?

Comment: Yes, package.json is at the root of the app folder.

Comment: What do you mean by you don't know what file your console.log is written in... what file did YOU write the text `console.log("endpoint is " + endpoint);` ???

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. It's in index.js.

Comment: No. First it complained that index.html wasn't in public. I moved it there, and now it says `Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined`. I have no idea what it's referring to. This code worked perfectly before I tried adding the env var.

Comment: well.... the version of react-scripts that you had before does not support environment variables unfortunately. I would recommend using the `create-react-app` command line tool to scaffold a new project to see how its setup. maybe there are just a few small differences

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!! I'd give you all my points if I could!!!

Comment: upvoting my answer wouldn't hurt  :p

Comment: To clarify why you didn't see it: "Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running."

Answer (score 0):

Dont sure, if it actual for you, **CNDyson**, but I think it might be helpful for newers like me:

1. *`npm install --save dotenv`*
2. create *`.env`* file in the root directory
3. declare there `REACT_APP_**VARIABLE_NAME** = dont forget about REACT_APP`
4. use it like this: `process.env.REACT_APP_**VARIABLE_NAME**`

Highly recommend to explore these links:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ -official documentaion

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv - dotenv

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that usually you want to access the environments variables present on the server that host your application.

With the described solution you will never be able to do `docker run --env FOO="value of foo" my-org/my-app`
then access `FOO` in the app like `process.env["FOO"]`.

`create-react-app` bundle the environment variables that are defined when you run `yarn build`.

If you want, for example, access the environment variables defined in the docker container check out: [react-envs](https://github.com/garronej/react-envs)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first create a file named env.local beside package.json
and try to secure environment variables REACT_APP_YOUR ENV FILE NAME

now set the secured name to your firebase file and push it

as simple as that